# Why electric lines of parallel-plate capacitor are illustrated only being also parallel?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

In the animation, you probably saw, illustrated how dipole antenna radiates, being "developed" from capacitor:

[image]

Why curved lines appears only with angle between plates?

As known, single electric charge is the source of radial electric field, two charges generate field as drown below:

[image]

Why, by this logic field of parallel plate capacitor is strictly parallel but now as drawn below?

[image]

Even if plate consists of the conductor and overlapping dielectric, and we assume the case of idealization, there still should be line going outside, no?

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes, but I don't think the animation was intended to be a perfect representation.

Comment: @JonCuster "yes" - there should be curved lines even for parallel plate capacitor?

Comment: There is some slight curvature near the edges, although for plate-to-plate spacings much smaller than the lateral extent of the plates it really isn't much at all. But the fringing fields can be important, such as for early cyclotrons.

Comment: @JonCuster why slight? Why not as just for two charges as I draw?

Comment: @JonCuster, if to consider a vacuum as dielectric between plates, why it should not be as drawn?

Answer (score 1):

> Why, by this logic field of parallel plate capacitor is strictly
> parallel but not as drawn below?

The capacitor at the start of the first animation, with only parallel field lines confined between the plates, is an idealization. All real capacitors have fringe effects at the edges of the plates where field lines extend outside the volume between the plates and are curved, as shown in your last illustration.

> Can You explain why in case of idealization there should not be
> outside curviness?

The equation for the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor as a function of the physical characteristics of the capacitor is based on the assumption that the electric field is totally confined to the volume of the space between the capacitor plates as shown in FIG 1 below. That equation is

$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$

where $A$ is the area of the plates ($m^2$), $d$ is the plate separation ($m$) and $\epsilon$ is the electrical permittivity of the dielectric between the plates (Farads/m).

However, as I've already said, in actuality the electric field lines are not confined to that volume. They extend to the space beyond the edges, as shown in FIG 2. This is referred to as the "edge" or "fringe" effect. The fact that the field lines extend beyond the edges of the plates means the actual capacitance is greater than that predicted by the above equation, since the effective area of the plates is greater than the actual area. To calculate what the actual capacitance would be involves  complex mathematical modeling.

To get around this, one can minimize the influence of the edge effects by reducing the percentage of the total number of field lines that are outside the volume between the plates. This can be accomplished by having the separation the $d$ between the plates be much less than the linear dimensions of the plate, as shown in FIG 3.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can You explain why in case of idealization there should not be outside curviness?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd I've updated my answer to respond to your follow up question. Hope it helps.

Comment: So You write, that real capacitor will have outside curves because of 
surface irregularities. Let's consider theoretical ideal crystal lattice, plates itself are an entire peace of metal (no dielectrics components), capacitor placed in the vacuum. Why in this case, there should not be outside curves?

Comment: It's not because of "surface irregularities".  It's because the charge located at the edges have electric field lines that extend beyond the edges of the plates.  You are overcomplicating this.

Comment: But all charges, have lines that extends the plates, and even in case of any idealization. I drew another illustration, that probably illustrates idealization You mean (pinned to question). Why in this case there should not be outside lines (as I drew)?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd I can't make sense of your diagram or your comments. Sorry, but it appears I can't get through to you and have no more time to spend on this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help, anyway